# convert vector to list

Tags: java, list, vector

How to convert a vector to a list?

Comment: A `Vector` *is* a `List`, it doesn't need converting. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`Vector`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) is a concrete class that implements the [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface so technically it is already a `List`. You can do this:

```
List list = new Vector();
```

or:

```
List<String> list = new Vector<String>();
```

(assuming a `Vector` of `String`s).

If however you want to convert it to an [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which is the closest `List` implementation to a `Vector~ in the Java Collections Framework then just do this:

```
List newList = new ArrayList(vector);
```

or for a generic version, assuming a `Vector` of `String`s:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(vector);
```

Comment: This also appears true for the inverse, e.g. `Vector newVector<String> = new Vector<String>(someStringArrayList);`

Answer (score 4):

If you want a utility method that converts an generic Vector type to an appropriate ArrayList, you could use the following:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> toList(Vector<T> source) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(source);
}
```

In your code, you would use the utility method as follows:

```
public void myCode() {
    List<String> items = toList(someVector);
    System.out.println("items => " + items);
}
```

You can also use the built-in java.util.Collections.list(Enumeration) as follows:

```
public void myMethod() {
    Vector<String> stringVector = new Vector<String>();
    List<String> theList = Collections.list(stringVector.elements());
    System.out.println("theList => " + theList);
}
```

But like someone mentioned below, a Vector is-a List! So why would you need to do this? Perhaps you don't want some code you use to know it's working with a Vector - perhaps it is inappropriately down-casting and you wish to eliminate this code-smell. You could then use

```
// the method i give my Vector to can't cast it to Vector
methodThatUsesList( Collections.unmodifiableList(theVector) );
```

if the List should be modified. An off-the-cuff mutable wrapper is:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(final List<T> vector) {
    return new AbstractList<T>() {
        public E get(int index) { return vector.get(index); }
        public int size() { return vector.size(); }
        public E set(int index, E element) { return vector.set(index, element); }
        public void add(int index, E element) { vector.add(index, element); }
        public E remove(int index) { return vector.remove(index); }
    }
}
```