# How to populate ArrayList after getting it from the webservice in Android

Tags: android

i am new to android and this my first time using AsyncTask. I made a very simple web service which returns ArrayList,  like

```
package pk.mazars.basitMahmood.weatherReport;

public class WeekDays {

    private String name;
    private String weather;
    private float temperature;

    public  WeekDays(String name, String weather, float temperature) {      
        this.name = name;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.temperature = temperature;         
    } //end of constructor  
    //--------------Getters and Setters 
} //end of class WeekDays

public class WeatherReport {

    public ArrayList<WeekDays> weatherReport() {

        ArrayList<WeekDays> weatherList = new ArrayList<WeekDays>();
        weatherList.add(new WeekDays("Monday", "Cloudy", 29.5F));
        weatherList.add(new WeekDays("Tuesday", "Normal", 32.3F));
        weatherList.add(new WeekDays("Wednesday", "Sunny", 37.7F));
        weatherList.add(new WeekDays("Thursday", "Cold", 20.2F));
        weatherList.add(new WeekDays("Friday", "Normal", 31.4F));
        weatherList.add(new WeekDays("Saturday", "Rainy", 22.6F));
        weatherList.add(new WeekDays("Sunday", "Rainy", 27.9F));

        return weatherList;     
    }
} //end of class WeatherReport
```

Then on the android side i used the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnStart;
    MyTask objMyTask;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                objMyTask = new MyTask(MainActivity.this);              
                objMyTask.execute();                
            }           
            }); //end of anonymous class        
        } //end of onCreate()    
    } //end of class MainActivity
```

and here is my task

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<?>> {

    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    Object result = null;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {      
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity ;          
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {     
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (dialog == null) {           
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity);          
        }           
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait. Your authentication is in progress");       
        dialog.show();      
    } //end of onPreExecute()

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<?> doInBackground(Void... params) {     
        callWebService();           
        return null;        
    } //end of doInBackground()

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<?> result) {     
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();   
    } //end of onPostExecute()

} //end of class MyTask
```

Here is the webservice method

```
 private void callWebService() {
    ...       
     try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = false;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);

        result = envelope.getResponse();

        if (result instanceof ArrayList<?>) {               
            ArrayList<?> weatherList = (ArrayList<?>)result;                
            for (int i=0; i<weatherList.size(); i++)                    
                Object weekDay = weatherList.get(i);
                System.out.println();                   
            }

        } else {

        }

     } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {            
         Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Service is not connected, Please make sure your server is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }  catch(Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();                            
     }      
} //end of callWebService()
```

At line

```
result = envelope.getResponse();
```

i get ArrayList like

[image]

But then i don't know that how can i get the data from the List. After reaching line

```
if (result instanceof ArrayList<?>) {..}
```

The control is transferred to `onPostExecute()` method and here i get result null. How can i populate the data after getting the result from ArrayList. Also as i am trying to populate data in the callwebService method. How can i get the ArrayLIst in the `onPostExecute(ArrayList<?> result)`result variable. Because my method is returning ArrayList and return result is transferred to `onPostExecute()` method from `doInBackground()` method. Also in `doInBackground()` method where can i check for `isCancel()` like

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {     
    for (int i = 1; i <100; i++) {                  
        if (isCancelled()) {                
            break;              
        } else {                
            System.out.println(i);               
            callWebService();                                   
        }

    } //end of for()                
    return null;        
} //end of doInBackground()
```

But if i check inside for loop, then my `callWebService()` method call 100 times . So in my case is there any need to call the isCancelled() method.

Thanks

Comment: `objMyTask.cancel();` and you can [check it](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: One thing that is confusing me that my `protected ArrayList<?> doInBackground(Void... params)` return type is ArrayList and i am returning null in the method. Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes that is what i am asking. Is it true? Also you mean to say that when i get the ArrayList in result variable and then if i call `this.cancel()` then i will get the return value of my webService function in the onPostExecute(ArrayList<?> result) variable?

Comment: thats not right bro..you have to return your arraylist object..see my link of customized listview in first comment

Comment: I saw it. One thing that i got is that the parameters that doInBackground() is accepting are those, that we pass with the execute() call. Like you use `execute("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001")`. So doInBackground() is accepting String. Basically you are saying that i use the `url.openConnection();` to get the data from the url, then populate it in the list and then using that list i do the things in my activity as you did . Is it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13305/discussion-between-samir-mangroliya-and-basit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should be declared as `private ArrayList<?> callWebService()` and you should return your arrayList from that method when you are done.

Also as mentioned above you should check if your result object is returned as `Vector`. If it is returned as Vector modify it to ArrayList.

Finally, in the `doInBackround` of your AsyncTask you should change your `return null` code to `return callWebService();` since your `callWebService()` method will return the result ArrayList with the above modification. Then in your `onPostExecute(ArrayList<?> result)` the result variable will not be null but will have the result ArrayList from your webservice.

So with the bove modifications you will have something like this:

```
private ArrayList<?> callWebService() {
...       
 try {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);

    result = envelope.getResponse();

    if (result instanceof ArrayList<?>) {               
        ArrayList<?> weatherList = (ArrayList<?>)result;                
        for (int i=0; i<weatherList.size(); i++)                    
            Object weekDay = weatherList.get(i);
            System.out.println();                   
        }

    } else {

    }

    return result;

 } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {            
     Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Service is not connected, Please make sure your server is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}  catch(Exception e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();                            
 }      
 } //end of callWebService()
```

The AsyncTask:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<?>> {

ProgressDialog dialog = null;
Object result = null;
MainActivity mainActivity;

public MyTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {      
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity ;          
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {     
    super.onPreExecute();
    if (dialog == null) {           
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity);          
    }           
    dialog.setMessage("Please Wait. Your authentication is in progress");       
    dialog.show();      
} //end of onPreExecute()

@Override
protected ArrayList<?> doInBackground(Void... params) {     

    return callWebService();       
} //end of doInBackground()

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<?> result) {     
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    dialog.dismiss();   
} //end of onPostExecute()

} //end of class MyTask
```

You can change your Vector to Array list with something like this:

```
ArrayList<WeekDays> arraylist = new ArrayList<WeekDays>();
Collectios.copy(arraylist, vector_containing_the_data);
```

**Edit(Basit)
---------------------------------------------------------------**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Vector<?> result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (result != null) {

        for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {

            Object weekDay = result.get(i);

            if (weekDay instanceof SoapObject) {

                SoapObject weekDayObject = (SoapObject)weekDay;

                String objectName = weekDayObject.getName();  //WeekDays
                String dayName = weekDayObject.getProperty("name").toString();
                String weather = weekDayObject.getProperty("weather").toString();
                String temp = weekDayObject.getProperty("temperature").toString();

            } //end of if (weekDay instanceof SoapObject)

        } //end of for (int i=0; i<result.size();...)

    } //end of if (result != null)

    dialog.dismiss();

} //end of onPostExecute()
```

But i think this should be done in the doBackGround() method and after populating the values in the bean. Then i should use that bean in my onPostExecute() method, to update the UIThread. But this code is working fine for me.

Comment: Hhmm you mean to say as i am using right now `public ArrayList<WeekDays> weatherReport()`. So instead of using `<WeekDays>`. I should use here `<?>`? But what's wrong with the public. Is there any special reason to change it to private. Yup i checked it with the `if (result instanceof Vector)` and it is working. But how can i change Vector to ArrayList?

Comment: I changed the method, but i am getting error that `can not return a void result` . Here are the changes `protected ArrayList<?> doInBackground(ArrayList<?>... params) {   return callWebService();
  } //end of doInBackground()`

Comment: You should also change the declaration of callWebService() from void to ArrayList<?>.

Comment: I did. But now i am using this code to change the vector to ArrayList. I followed this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973705/convert-vector-to-list to convert Vector to ArrayList but it isn't working `if (result instanceof Vector) {
  ArrayList<?> weatherList = new ArrayList<?>(result);`  error is `can not instiate the type ArrayList<?>`

Comment: My bad, sorry. You should instantiate your ArrayList giving it a specific type for your example there are two ways: ArrayList<WeekDays> weekdays = new ArrayList<WeekDays>(); or ArrayList<?> weekdays = new ArrayList<WeekDays>();

Comment: HHmm but my WeekDays class is on the server. Means in the webService. Do i also need to make the copy of WeekDays class in my android code? Because if i use `if (result instanceof Vector) { ArrayList<?> weatherList = new ArrayList<WeekDays>(result);`. Then i get error that `The constructor ArrayList<WeekDays>(Object) is undefined....WeekDays can not be resolved to a type.` And clearly i have no WeekDays class in my android project?

Comment: From what i understand I believe you should have a WeekDays class in your android project. The problem you may encounter is that Android will not get that your WeekDays class defined in your webservice is the same class as the WeekDays class defined in your Android project. If you encounter that problem, maybe you should change the returned object of your web service to not be a custom class but (in my opinion) a JSON or an XML String and do the parsing in your android project generating your ArrayList of WeekDays class type objects.

Comment: Hmm can you please tell me one thing. I am using code `Object prop = weekDayObject.getProperty(j).toString();`. This give me the values that i want. Like first time it gives me monday, then the weather and then the float(39.5) and so on. But there is no indication that these belongs to WeekDays class on the server. Also as i am using on server side like setWeather, setName, there is no indication what the attributes are, i am getting just values. As i added objects on the server side, i am getting here in the same manner. Is this approach ok? Just getting values with getProeprty and use it?

Comment: To tell you the truth, i have not used the approach you are describing before. But if this approach gives you the values you want in the correct order (in your case first:day, second: weather, third:temperature), i do not see a reason to not use it. You can take these raw values and instantiate an new instance of your WeekDay class defined in your Android app with the appropriate constructor or setter/getter methods. I would personally stick into a JSON String or an XML string returned by the webservice but if your approach works it is up to you of course to choose.

Comment: I think it's simple. Everything in the end when done seems simple... Anyways thanks for your help Anglo :)

Comment: Glad i could help (even a bit):)

Answer (score 0):

Your result object is returned as a Vector, not an ArrayList.

Try changing things to:

```
  if (result instanceof Vector) {               
            Vector weatherList = (Vector)result;
```

and see if you get anywhere.